# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'test' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Context: **SQL Server 2008**

I have a table `mytable` which contains two `NVARCHAR` columns `id`, `title`.

All data in the `id` column are in fact numeric, except one row which contains the value 'test'.

I want to get all ids between 10 and 15 so I need SQL Server to convert id column values to `INTEGER`.

I use `ISNUMERIC(id) = 1` to eliminate the non numeric values first but SQL Server is being rather weird with this query.

```
SELECT 
    in.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         id, title 
     FROM 
         mytable 
     WHERE 
         ISNUMERIC(id) = 1) in
WHERE 
    in.id BETWEEN 10 AND 15
```

This query causes the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'test' to
>   data type int.

The inner query eliminates the row with the 'test' id value so 'in' shouldn't contain it. Why is SQL Server still trying to convert it?

Am I missing something? How can I get around this?

P.S. I tried `WHERE CAST(in.id AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 10 AND 15` but didn't work either.

Comment: there is no guaranty that sql server will do the "isnumeric " before the "in between". That is why this function is always dangerous.

Comment: Please add sql server version.

Comment: @GuidoG yeah that's probably it. Is there a way around it?

Comment: the answer from cybernetic87 would be perfect, but I understand you have sql server 2008 ? that might be a problem

Comment: @GuidoG yeah I neglected to mention it. I edited my question.

Comment: Can you add the execution plan for your query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I should add one more way with XML style:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE CAST(id as xml).value('. cast as xs:decimal?','int') BETWEEN 10 AND 15
```

Convert `id` to XML, convert the value in `xs:decimal` and then convert to `integer`. If there is not numeric value it will be converted into `NULL`.

Here you can read about XML type casting rules ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191231.aspx)).

Comment: I tested this and it works. I had to change 'int' to 'bigINT' because some ids overflow but still, it's a great solution! Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Comment: Greate solution! Haven't thought of this yet... +1 from my side

Answer (score 19):

Use TRY_CONVERT function, it's very handy.

```
SELECT id, 
       title 
FROM   mytable 
where  TRY_CONVERT(int, id) is not NULL 
and    TRY_CONVERT(int, id) BETWEEN 10 and 15
```

TRY_CONVERT returns null if the conversion fails.

And for you error, I suppose that the Query Optimizer messes something up here. Take a look at the execution plan, maybe it's filtering values between 10 and 15 at the first place. My solution will always work.

As the other commenter said in your case the BETWEEN function is done before ISNUMERIC. Here is a simple example:

```
select * into #temp2
from (
select 'test' a
union
select cast(1 as varchar) a
union 
select cast(2 as varchar) a
union 
select cast(3 as varchar) a
)z


SELECT a FROM ( 
SELECT a FROM #temp2 WHERE ISNUMERIC(a) = 1
) b
WHERE b.a BETWEEN 10 AND 15
```

This simple query is an alternative:

```
SELECT a 
FROM #temp2 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(a) = 1 
and a BETWEEN 10 AND 15
```

Comment: Using isnumeric is always dangerous because you have no control over the execution plan, it might be called after the in between condition. This is a much better method

Comment: This would be perfect but unfortunately my Database has a compatibility level of SQL Server 2008 (100) and changing it is not an option for me.

Is there an alternative for 2008?

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` is available in SQL Server **2012** and newer -  doesn't work for SQL Server 2008 .....

Comment: The question wasn't tagged with the SQL Server version from the start.

Answer (score 4):

Could create a new field to do the search on:

```
Select id, title
    from (Select id, title, case id when 'test' then null else cast(id as int) end as trueint from mytable) n
    where n.trueint between 10 and 15
```

OR

```
Select id, title
from mytable
where case isnumeric(id) when 1 then cast(id as int) else null end between 10 and 15
```

Comment: I like this idea, +1 from my side, but it might be better to use something like `CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(id)=1 THEN id ELSE NULL END AS validNumber` and then `WHERE CAST(validNumber AS INT) BETWEEN ...`

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo. I have rethought it a little to just use the case statement in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to force the engine to work this in two steps:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id NVARCHAR(MAX),title NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl 
SELECT id, title FROM mytable WHERE ISNUMERIC(id) = 1;

SELECT t.*
FROM @tbl t
WHERE CAST(t.id AS INT) BETWEEN 10 AND 15
```